# null value in java

Tags: java, null

i am getting an string from using swing and i need to validate if it is not null
i use this code

```
if(site.equals(null)) {
    System.out.println("null");
} else  {
    System.out.println("notnull");
}
```

it always show "notnull" if there is null also

Comment: in case "site" is null, it will not say "notnull" but throw an NullPointerException. An object on which you can call equals can never be null, so something.equal(null) has to return false by contract. Use: if(site == null)

Answer (score 13):

To test for actual nullity, use `==` like this:

```
if (site == null)
```

Or indeed the conditional operator, for situations like the one shown:

```
System.out.println(site == null ? "null" : "notnull");
```

Note that a null reference is *not* the same as an empty string. How do you want an empty string to behave? If you truly had a null reference, then your current code would have thrown a `NullPointerException`.

The simplest way for testing an empty string is with the `isEmpty` method:

```
System.out.println(site.isEmpty() ? "empty" : "not empty");
```

Note:

- This will throw an exception if `site` really *is* null
- This will treat whitespace as irrelevant

If you want to test for null/empty/empty-or-whitespace there are various third-party libraries which have that functionality.

Comment: same thing is happening it says not null i used trim() also

Comment: i need to neglight the empty string the process should not start for empty string

Answer (score 6):

The problem is probably related to the textbox you are using will always return a string, just an empty one.

Change your check to the following and see if it works.

```
if(site.equals(""))
```

Note that this won't stop them from simply putting a space in though. you would need to trim the input first.

Comment: You should use String.isEmpty() instead of comparing it to "".

Comment: Good job of looking past what the questioner was asking and figuring out what he needed--wish I could give +2.

Comment: actually a better idiom is `"".equalsIgnoreCase(site);` it avoids the null pointer exception if site is null and IngnoreCase is faster when site != ""

Answer (score 1):

If it was null then it already gave you null pointer exception.Because you are invoking a method on null object. So It is better you use

```
if(site==null)
```

And for confirmation try this

```
if(site.equals(null)) {
System.out.println("null");
```

} else  {
    System.out.println(site);
    System.out.println("notnull");
}

This will print the value of site string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the string is being assigned `null` the value, and not `"null"` the string?

Comment: Any reason why I was downvoted?  That's a perfectly valid response.  Considering he has no control over the string he's being passed, someone else could have made that error.

Comment: +1 for psychic abilities though this would've been better as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

The String.equals() method only returns true if the argument is **not** null, and then only if the argument is an identical String. [See the documentation.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

You should initially be using a direct comparison to find out if either string is null, before you do a further check for equivalence.

```
   if (site == null) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stringutils class? Here is the link --> http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

You can check for string "nullness" and "emptiness" in a null-safe way and act accordingly